# Generalisation of 'derivatives are Baire 1'

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then its derivative $f'$ is Baire 1 (which essentially follows by the definition of derivative).

Do functions differentiable *almost everywhere* exhibit a similar kind of regularity?
In particular, let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable almost everywhere and let $g(x)$ be $f'(x)$ if the latter exists at $x$, and zero everywhere else.  Which function class does $g$ belong to?

Comment: Not an answer but still worth noting is the following result: A. Bruckner, *Differentiation of Real Functions* (2d ed, 1994), chapter 8 (“Derivatives a.e. and generalizations”), theorem 1.3 (rephrased to align with your notation): a necessary and sufficient condition on a function $g\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ for there to exists a function $f$ such that $f' = g$ almost everywhere is that $f$ be measurable and finite almost everywhere; furthermore, when this condition is satisfied, $f$ can be chosen continuous.

Comment: (The difference between the result in my previous comment and your question is that you impose $g(x)=0$ when $f'(x)$ does not exist, whereas the above result simply requires $f' = g$ almost everywhere. But I still think it's interesting enough to mention.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thanks for the answer, which is helpful: I am also interested in the behaviour of functions you mention ($f'=g$ ae), i.e. the what happens on the measure zero set is not that important.